# ...stream... result When using Message.CreateMessage() with XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader()

Tags: c#, xml, soap

This code works just fine sometimes. The ErrorXml const string is below:

```
     public Message GetErrorMessage(string code, string message, string actor)
    {
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format(ErrorXml, code, message, actor));

        var xdr = XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(bytes, 
                  new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
        return Message.CreateMessage(xdr, int.MaxValue, MessageVersion.Soap11);
    }
```

Here is the definition of the ErrorXml const:

```
private const string ErrorXml = @"<env:Envelopexmlns:env""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
                                   <env:Body>
                                       <env:Fault>
                                           <faultcode> {0} </faultcode>
                                           <faultstring> {1} </faultstring>
                                               <faultactor> {2} <faultactor>
                                           </env:Fault>
                                       </env:Body>
                                   </env:Envelope>
```

Now, the < body > tag of the result sometimes contains the following string ...stream..., which I challenge anyone to explain how I can search for without getting every Stream reference in existence. Also, how does one debug this error? Thanks!

Comment: It's really not clear what your issue is. What values results in the creation of this mystery error? A [mcve] would be helpful, or at the very least a copy of whatever this error xml is.

Comment: I understand this request on your part, and I will edit for greater clarity. However, I feel it does not fit this situation. What I am REALLY hoping to learn is this: what does "...stream..." mean? Why does it appear sometimes? How do I troubleshoot it? Has anybody here EVER seen "...stream..." as the entirety of the < body > tag? Thanks!